# Helvetica in Matplotlib with siunitx

Tags: matplotlib, latex

I would like to create my graphs to match my LaTeX document and use the Helvetica font for both.
In LaTeX I have

```
\usepackage{helvet}                                             
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

set.

The code in Python looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import locale

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [
    r'\usepackage[detect-all,locale=DE]{siunitx}',  #SI-Einheiten, Komma
    r'\usepackage{helvet}',                         #Helvetica als Schrift
    r'\usepackage{icomma}']                        
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.UTF-8")      
plt.ticklabel_format(useLocale=True)            

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [5, 6, 7.2, 8.1]
plt.plot(x, y, marker="o", label="setting1")
plt.xticks(np.arange(1.0, 4.2, step=0.5))
plt.xlabel("x (\si{\milli\metre})")
plt.ylabel("y (\si{\pascal})")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The problem is that "Pa" from the figure does not match the "Pa" in LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to my matplotlibrc file worked for me.

```
mathtext.fontset : custom
mathtext.it : Helvetica:italic
```

Also, I needed to have Helvetica-Oblique.ttf in my `/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf` directory. Olga Botvinnik has some good instructions in her blog. Someday, I'll put a similar set of instructions together on mine.

Note, that you're going to have to clear out your cache under `~/.matplotlib` in order to refresh this.

Matplotlib says that custom fontsets are not supported and this might all break in a future update of Matplotlib.

Comment: Adding the link to Olga Botvinnik's blog for reference: https://olgabotvinnik.com/blog/how-to-set-helvetica-as-the-default-sans-serif-font-in/